# How to create a desktop application which allows you to navigate to different pages?

Tags: java

I have experience in PHP web development. I am trying to learn to create a desktop application in Java. My first roadblock is, how do I create a desktop application which allows you to navigate to different pages like as possible in a web application?

Comment: Are you talking about JSP? or Servlets?

Comment: Install Java, Apache Tomcat. Learn JSP (and Servlets).

Comment: Do you mean in Swing applications?  Or a web site?

Comment: I think I am talking about Swing applications. Im trying to create a GUI that can simulate webpages. It's definitely not webpages.

Comment: Yes. Im trying to switch from Web Application to Desktop Application. stoyanrr gave me a better explanation of what I want than me. I will update my original post.

Comment: I clarified it more. In the future, please formulate questions carefully.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean desktop and not Web applications, then you should look at appropriate desktop application frameworks. These are different from JSP or Play!.

- Swing is the classic one, but kind of old (and Oracle is no more investing in it)
- SWT comes from the Eclipse community. Powerful, open source, etc.
- [Java FX](http://javafx.com/) is seen by some as the modern successor of Swing. Oracle actively promotes it in conferences, etc.
- [Griffon](http://griffon.codehaus.org/) - easy to use and a very good choice if you don't mind dealing a programming language different than Java (Groovy in this case). It also offers support for Java.

Answer (score 1):

i think you are looking for JSP,
you need to use a application (web container) server which can run your JSP.

look at [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/), one of the most widely used web containers for Java.
here are some samples

- [Tutorial](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/%7Ehall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/)
- [Another tutorial](http://www.jsptut.com/)

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.

The main option you'll hear about is [Java EE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/index.html), which includes JSPs, servlets, and such. These run in a "container" that provides the framework. [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) is a very popular open-source container which provides for JSPs and servlets (it's not a full-on Java EE container, but it doesn't sound like you need one).

The [Play! framework](http://playframework.org) is another increasingly popular option. It breaks from the Java EE mold and shoots for rapid development cycles and such.

Another option is to use [Mongrel2](http://mongrel2.org/) with a Java connector.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want in Java you should make a *Web Application*. Considering that you are coming from PHP developement experience, I suggest you to start with [JSP](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/jsp/index.html) technology, which is quite similar to php (for similar I mean that you have your HTML page and you can embed java code by using special tags).
[This](http://www.jsptut.com/) is a tutorial that could be useful to you in order to start building a web application.

If you are using [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) as your IDE, you could start by creating a new *Dynamic Web Project*, letting eclipse build most of the bolierplate code for you (you can do this with other IDEs though).

This is a simple JSP page that you can use as a start:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Html code</p>
  <p><% out.print("Java code"); %></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Once you will be familiar with JSP technology, you will notice that JSP have some limitations especially if you want to build complex web applications (one of them is that embedding java code into a web page could be confusing and hard to debug, and it's considered a bad practice nowadays). But, having that knowledge, you could easily move to some more complex and proficient technologies, suck as [JSF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/javaserverfaces-139869.html).